# Reflection performance

Tags: java, reflection

I have a collection with one to 100 objects of a certain type. These objects have over 100 attributes. I have to traverse all objects in the collection and check for a certain attibutes to do something with them. The actual methods depends on a properties file so I cannot know beforehand which one I have to call. I have done it with reflection in this way:

```
for (MyObject mo : myObjectList){

    for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector
                        .getBeanInfo(mo.getClass())
                        .getPropertyDescriptors()) {

        method = propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod();

        if (method != null){
            //Here I check if the attribute is in the properties file and do the job
        }

    }
}
```

This is implemented in a webservice that is called by several applications and the load can be theoretically high.

The reflection method is computer expensive but it is the only way I found to be able to do the task without changing the code if tomorrow a new attribute is addressed by the task.

I have read (don't remember the source) that the most expensive part of reflection is looking for the methods more than calling them so I have been thinking that maybe reversing the loops (i.e. look for the methods and then call the method by reflection for each object) is a performance wise change. Something like this:

```
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector
                        .getBeanInfo(MyObject.getClass())
                        .getPropertyDescriptors()) {

    if (method != null){
       for (MyObject mo : myObjectList){
         //Do the job here
       }
    }

}
```

There is any grounds for reversing the loops?

Comment: Note that `Method` and `Field` instances are typically cached, so only the first retrieval is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually *measured* the performance of this ? I suspect the impact is negligible compared to the network and marshalling overhead of your webservice.

If you genuinely think this is an issue, can you retrieve the `Method` objects in advance for the objects (or at least perform this operation in a lazy fashion - when required and cache for later use. I note Sotirios' comment above, and caching may be redundant if so)

Comment: After testing I think you are right. Changing the loops order have a minimun impact in the webservice response time. It seems by the test that the reversed-loops are a bit more time efficient in the worst case scenario but the times are very similar and deeper test should be made to verify it. Thanks :)